# ComboViewer, How can I get the selected item of a comboViewer?

Tags: java, get, swt, viewer

I created a ComboViewer

```
    final ComboViewer comboViewer = new ComboViewer(shlFreeViews, SWT.NONE);
    final Combo combo = comboViewer.getCombo();
    combo.setVisibleItemCount(4);
    combo.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Segoe UI", 13, SWT.NORMAL));
    combo.setItems(new String[] {"5", "10", "15", "20"});
    combo.setBounds(356, 172, 126, 25);
    combo.setText("5");
```

The problem is that when I open the program I have to select a number of my comboviewer and then I have to use this number for do a simple addition. What the code to get the selected number of the comboviewer?

Answer (score 6):

You can either add an `ISelectionChangedListener` to the `ComboViewer` to get notified when the selection changes, or you can get it manually. The procedure is the same:

```
StructuredSelection sel = (StructuredSelection) viewer.getSelection();
YourDataType element = (YourDataType) sel.getFirstElement();
```

Comment: @user3850946 You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24841539/edit) your question and add code.

Comment: final ComboViewer comboViewer = new ComboViewer(shlFreeViews, SWT.NONE);
    final Combo combo = comboViewer.getCombo();
    combo.setVisibleItemCount(4);
    combo.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Segoe UI", 13, SWT.NORMAL));
    combo.setItems(new String[] {"5", "10", "15", "20"});
    combo.setBounds(356, 172, 126, 25);
    combo.setText("5");                                                 StructuredSelection sel = (StructuredSelection) viewer.getSelection();
YourDataType element = (YourDataType) sel.getFirstElement();

Comment: @user3850946 Please edit your question and add the code there. And shouldn't you know best if it's correct and working?